# CloudML job + verbosity == Error

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Runnning the `dataeng-machine-learning` codelab on step `9. 4. Feature Engineering`.

The notebook step for running a tarin job is:

`%%bash
OUTDIR=gs://${BUCKET}/taxifare/ch4/taxi_trained
JOBNAME=lab4a_$(date -u +%y%m%d_%H%M%S)
echo $OUTDIR $REGION $JOBNAME
gsutil -m rm -rf $OUTDIR
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOBNAME \
   --region=$REGION \
   --module-name=trainer.task \
   --package-path=${REPO}/courses/machine_learning/feateng/taxifare/trainer \
   --job-dir=$OUTDIR \
   --staging-bucket=gs://$BUCKET \
   --scale-tier=BASIC \
   --runtime-version=1.0 \
   -- \
   --train_data_paths="gs://$BUCKET/taxifare/ch4/taxi_preproc/train*" \
   --eval_data_paths="gs://${BUCKET}/taxifare/ch4/taxi_preproc/valid*"  \
   --output_dir=$OUTDIR \
   --num_epochs=100`

That works great no matter how many time I run it.

However if I run:

`%%bash
OUTDIR=gs://${BUCKET}/taxifare/ch4/taxi_trained
JOBNAME=lab4a_$(date -u +%y%m%d_%H%M%S)
echo $OUTDIR $REGION $JOBNAME
gsutil -m rm -rf $OUTDIR
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOBNAME \
   --region=$REGION \
   --module-name=trainer.task \
   --package-path=${REPO}/courses/machine_learning/feateng/taxifare/trainer \
   --job-dir=$OUTDIR \
   --staging-bucket=gs://$BUCKET \
   --scale-tier=BASIC \
   --runtime-version=1.0 \
   -- \
   --train_data_paths="gs://$BUCKET/taxifare/ch4/taxi_preproc/train*" \
   --eval_data_paths="gs://${BUCKET}/taxifare/ch4/taxi_preproc/valid*"  \
   --output_dir=$OUTDIR \
   --num_epochs=100 \ 
   --verbosity DEBUG`

Job fails after about 40 sec. with this in the logs:
`The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 2. Termination reason: Error.`

I've found this usage in here:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction#cloud-train-single

So I guesss it's ok to use.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the only difference the verbosity flag? Or is there some other meaningful difference I'm missing (or maybe copy-and-paste error)?

Comment: unless i'm mistaken it's the only difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that every argument after the "-- \" line is a pass through to the tensorflow code and is therefore dependent on the individual sample code.

In this case, the "--verbosity" flag isn't supported by the sample you are running.  Looking at the [samples repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=VERBOSITY&type=), it looks like the only sample that has that flag is the [census estimator sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/867832752380c89a47d6a7a9df44ca4dae862a5d/census/estimator/trainer/task.py).

Comment: Great - 10x. The codelab tells you that you get a certain MSE just not how you can validate that claim. It'd be nice to have that MSE output into the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The taxifare example is currently hardcoded to INFO, and the code doesn't parse the --verbose flag.

Comment: Missed that ... Teaches me to answer stack overflow on my phone